# creating new elements using object oriented javascript

Tags: javascript

I am learning how to write object oriented javascript. I have a simple class to create div elements, but when I test the code no new elements are created. Am I doing this correctly? I am using the following code:

```
function elementCreation(elementParent, elementId, elementText) {
    this.elementParent = document.getElementsByTagName(elementParent)[0];
    this.elementId = elementId;
    this.elementHtml = elementText;
    this.elementMake = function (type) {
        newElement = document.createElement(type);
        // add new element to the dom
        this.elementParent.appendChild(newElement);
    };
}

var newObject = new elementCreation('body', 'testdiv', 'some text here!!!');
newObject.elementMake('div');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works perfectly, congratulations.

You simply can't see an empty div without styling.

See [here a demonstration with styling](http://jsfiddle.net/wRt38/) :

```
div {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background-color:red;   
}​
```

Note that if your construction parameters were intended for the construction of the child element, you have to put them to some use. For example :

```
function elementCreation(elementParent, elementId, elementText) {
    this.elementParent = document.getElementsByTagName(elementParent)[0];
    this.elementId = elementId;
    this.elementHtml = elementText;
    this.elementMake = function (type) {
        newElement = document.createElement(type);
        // add new element to the dom
        this.elementParent.appendChild(newElement);
        newElement.innerHTML = elementText;
    };
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/ff3Cz/)

I won't try to use the `elementId` parameter : if you define a function, it's probably to call it more than once and an id can't be used more than once in HTML.

Comment: oh ok i see now that it created the div, but how do I apply the id and the text? `'testdiv', 'some text here!!!'` did show.

Comment: I think the OP is expecting/hoping that the supplied text be rendered in the DIV (some text here!!!)

Comment: The code doesn't work quite perfectly, because it doesn't set the element HTML or ID.

Comment: @MrCode Both of your concerns were addressed in my answer long before your comment. Please refresh this page.

Answer (score 0):

The div is being created but you aren't setting it's content as your third argument `elementText`.

```
    newElement = document.createElement(type);
    newElement.innerHTML = this.elementHtml; // <-- set its content
    newElement.id = this.elementId; // <-- set the ID
    // add new element to the dom
    this.elementParent.appendChild(newElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Added compatibility with firefox when setting text content, then associated the id attribute to the new element. I also tried another approach that could be easier to complexify.

What about:

```
function elementCreation(args) {
    this.parent = args.parent;
    this.id = args.id;
    this.text = args.text;

    this.make = function(type) {
        var el = document.createElement(type);
        el.id = this.id;

        // firefox do not support innerText, some others do not support textContent
        if (typeof el.innerText != "undefined") {
            el.innerText = this.text;
        } else {
            el.textContent = this.text;
        }

        this.parent.appendChild(el);
    }
}

new elementCreation({
    parent: document.body,
    id: 'div1',
    text: 'some text here!!!'
}).make('div');
```

You can try it [with this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G9sQe/1/).